# Class index table columns doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I am creating my code's documentation using Doxygen.
The problem is, there are quite large number of classes and Doxygen generates a class index that is vertically as well as horizontally scroll able.
I mean, there are a large number of columns in that HTML table.
How do I change the number of columns to say 1 or 2 which will make the class index page only vertically scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [alphabetical index](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#alphabetical_index) configuration file options. Specifically, see the `COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX` option. From the doxygen manual:

> If the alphabetical index is enabled ... then the `COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX` tag can be used to specify the number of columns in which this list will be split (can be a number in the range [1..20])